# console cout animation - C++

Tags: c++, windows, console

I would like to animate a 40x20 block of characters that I am `cout`-ing.  I would like to clear the console with `system("cls");` and then have the next block on character instantly appear.  Currently the next block is coming on typewriter style.

The most simplest answer to my question would just to have a 20 line by 40 character oss stream cout at once, instead of doing it typewriter style.

Main.cpp:

```
    mazeCreator.cout();
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
```

cout()

```
void MazeCreator::cout() {
    char wallChar = (char) 219;
    char pavedChar = (char) 176;
    char lightChar = ' ';
    char startChar = 'S';
    char finishChar = 'F';
    char errorChar = '!';
    char removedWallChar = 'R';
    char landmarkLocationChar = 'L';

    ostringstream oss;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        oss << " ";
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            if (mazeArray[row][col] == wall)
                oss << wallChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == paved)
                oss << pavedChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == light)
                oss << lightChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == start)
                oss << startChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == finish)
                oss << finishChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == removedWall)
                oss << removedWallChar;
            else if (mazeArray[row][col] == landmarkLocation)
                oss << landmarkLocationChar;
            else
                oss << errorChar;
        }
        oss << "\n";
    }
    oss << "\n\n";

    cout << oss.str();
}
```

Comment: I assume this is for Windows?

Comment: You'll need to give more detail.

Comment: Do you mean you can see it being drawn? You can use a buffer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @chris That looks like what I want but I might need some help implementing it

Comment: Is that the actual code?  The method returns void, but the main function is outputting the result of the method.

Comment: @VaughnCato No its not. It is a simplified version The outputting is done in the cout() method.  Modified it to make more sense.

Comment: In that case, maybe the issue is not flushing cout.

Comment: What is typewriter style? o.ô

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain two 2D arrays in your code, one with the current block of characters on the screen (let's call it `cur`) and one with the next block (let's call it `next`).

Assume `cur` stores the block that's on screen right now. Set up the next block by writing into the `next` array. When you're ready to put it on the screen, loop through `cur` and `next` simultaneously, and *only for characters where they differ*, use `SetConsoleCursorPosition` to jump to that location and write the new character.

Once you've done that, copy the contents of `next` into `cur` and move on to the next block.

**UPDATE**: Here's an example:

```
class console_buffer
{
public:
    console_buffer(int rows, int columns) 
                   // start out with spaces
                 : cur(rows, vector<char>(columns, ' ')), 
                   next(rows, vector<char>(columns, ' '))
    {
    }

    void sync()
    {
        // Loop over all positions
        for (int row = 0; row < cur.size(); ++row)
            for (int col = 0; col < cur[row].size(); ++col)

                // If the character at this position has changed
                if (cur[row][col] != next[row][col])
                {
                    // Move cursor to position
                    COORD c = {row, col};
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);

                    // Overwrite character
                    cout.put(next[row][col]);
                }

         // 'next' is the new 'cur'
         cur = next;
    }

    void put(char c, int row, int col)
    {
        next[row][col] = c;
    }
private:
    vector<vector<char> > cur;
    vector<vector<char> > next;
};

...

int main()
{
    console_buffer buf(40, 20);

    // set up first block
    ... some calls to buf.put() ...

    // make first block appear on screen
    buf.sync();

    // set up next block
    ... some calls to buf.put()

    // make next block appear on screen
    buf.sync();

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I would rather not maintain two 2D arrays.  I would rather just have a way to instantly cout an ostringstream.

Comment: @michaellindahl: I would *rather* just have code write itself for me, but hey, we all face disappointment from time to time. At the end of the day, you either have code that works, or the satisfaction of having avoided doing things you'd *rather* not do ;)

Comment: Touche.  I'm not quite sure what you even mean my maintaining two 2-D arrays... Do you want to give me some example code?  I'm a novice with c++

Comment: @michaellindahl: there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement double buffering using [CreateConsoleScreenBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Something along these lines should work. I've used this once, quite a while ago, so it might not be perfect.

```
HANDLE current = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

HANDLE buffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer (
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
    NULL
);

WriteConsole (/*fill with what you're drawing*/);

system ("cls"); //clear this screen before swapping    
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer (buffer);

WriteConsole (/*do it to the other one now*/);

system ("cls");    
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer (current); //swap again

//repeat as needed

CloseHandle (buffer); //clean up
```

Comment: How can I just use an os stream with WriteConsole?  The simplest approach that I am looking for would be just to print out a oss stream instantly.

Comment: Well, even `cout` can't put it all out at once. If you do it repeatedly with little time in between outputs, it will start to flicker. To get the C-style data from the stringstream, you could use `os.str().c_str()`.

Comment: That is giving me an error.  And yes I am an idiot.  Hand-holding is highly recommended.

Comment: @michaellindahl, What kind of error? Filling in the `WriteConsole` shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: `WriteConsole (os.str().c_str());` says there is not enough arguments.

Comment: @michaellindahl, there's a link to it in the column on the left-hand side of the page I linked to in my post. The site is an excellent reference for Windows API functions. It needs which to output to, the characters, the number of characters, etc. There's a good explanation of each parameter. The API was made in C, and it's not quite as user-friendly as it could be. There are classes for pretty much all of it if you'd like something like MFC better.